# How to merge set of columns based on a common field

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, merge

How can I do the following in bash.

a) Take out columns 1,2,6

b) Row is identified by field 'packetId'; There can be one or 2 rows with same 'packetId'; if there are 2 rows with same packetId, then append the first row with the last field of the second row

c) If there is only one row for a 'packetId', then ignore that row and donot print

**Input**

```
SequenceId,TimeStamp,packetId,size,secondaryid,eventType,randomfield,Source,Destination,SystemTime 
1,3:41:24,1,100,xyz,event1,abc,S1,D1,1586989874

2,3:41:25,1,100,xyz,event2,abc,S1,D1,1586989877

3,3:41:26,2,100,xyz,event1,abc,S1,D1,1586989879

4,3:41:26,3,100,xyz,event1,abc,S1,D1,1586989871

5,3:41:26,3,100,xyz,event2,abc,S1,D1,1586989879
```

**output**

```
packetId,size,secondaryid,randomfield,Source,Destination,SystemTime,OtherSystemTime

1,100,xyz,abc,S1,D1,1586989874,1586989877

3,100,xyz,abc,S1,D1,1586989871,1586989879
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it all in `awk`, but it's simpler to use `cut` to first remove the fields you don't care about:

```
$ cut -d, -f3-5,7- input.csv |
  awk -F, 'NR == 1 { print $0 ",OtherSystemTime"; next }
           { if ($1 in seen) print seen[$1] "," $NF; else seen[$1] = $0 }'
packetId,size,secondaryid,randomfield,Source,Destination,SystemTime,OtherSystemTime
1,100,xyz,abc,S1,D1,1586989874,1586989877
3,100,xyz,abc,S1,D1,1586989871,1586989879
```

Comment: How would I add a new column, which is diff of last 2 columns (OtherSystemTime-SystemTime) to above solution?